# Why calling a makefile with -f option breaks rules calling sub-makes?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Consider the following Makefile

```
prereqrule:
        @echo "Executing prereqrule"

submakerule:
        @echo "Executing submakerule"

check: prereqrule
        +@$(MAKE) submakerule
```

I run the check rule from another directory. First approach works the second does not .

```
$ make -C MakefileQuestion check
Executing prereqrule
Executing submakerule
```

The submakerule cannot be found with `-f`

```
$ make -f MakefileQuestion/Makefile check
Executing prereqrule
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `submakerule'.  Stop.
make: *** [check] Error 2
```

What is the reason that the `-f` version cannot find the submakerule in the spawned sub-make call ?

---

I know one way “fix” this. Using a `$THIS_FILE` parameter.

```
THIS_FILE := $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))
workingcheck: prereqrule
        +@$(MAKE) -f $(THIS_FILE) submakerule
```

Works for both approaches

```
$ make -C MakefileQuestion workingcheck
Executing prereqrule
Executing submakerule
$  make -f MakefileQuestion/Makefile workingcheck
Executing prereqrule
Executing submakerule
```

I am mostly interested **why** the `-f` approach does not work. What is different in `make`’s implementation for the two use cases (`-C` and `-f`) such that the second one needs the `-f $THIS_FILE` passed to the submake ?

Answer (score 0):

The value of `MAKE` variable is the file name with which make was invoked. It does not contain any other parameters, like `-f` or `-t`. If it did, you would not be able to run any other recursive make commands except that you ran in the first place, which makes no sense.

`-C` works because it tells your shell to change directory first. This makes it possible to run subsequent `make`s without providing explicitly the directory.

Comment: How this is behavior I see related to the $(MAKE) variable. According to its [doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/MAKE-Variable.html) it takes values like ` /bin/make`, in my case it is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make`

Comment: Also I am not asking why do I need to pass `-f $(THIS_FILE)` explicitly. I do not understand why it is necessary at the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what is going on now. I had a more fundamental confusion about make.

The following rule

```
check: prereqrule
        +@$(MAKE) submakerule
```

causes a

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make submakerule`

execution from `pwd`.

Since the run directory did not contain any Makefiles, make printed that error.

Similar to this.

```
~/DirWithoutMakefile$ make check
make: *** No rule to make target `check'.  Stop.
```

Passing a `-f $(THIS_FILE)` uses the right makefile instead of not finding any makefile in `pwd`.